# How to represent an SQL query graphically

Tags: sql, database-design, erd

I have a SQL Select query with many joins between tables, I want to know which kind of diagram could represent it graphically in order to visualise the joins between tables and their types (differentiate between INNERs and LEFTs) ?

I did this simple schema to represent my query but I'm searching for a known and better type of diagram :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is a variation of an [Entity Relationship Diagram](https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/), where the different line-ends indicate the relationship type. When structuring a database, I believe this type of model is most common and easily understood.

[image]

Comment: I thought of using that one but I want something that could reprensent joins directly rather than just presenting the relations between the tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use crow's foot notation for Enitity Relationship Diagram where you can specify the relationship(one to many, one to one) as well as the optionality(enitityA has exactly one of enitityB OR enitityA has 0 or 1 of enitityB). In your case optionality might represent the type of join you need to do. Why exactly you need to specify the join types in an ERD?

Answer (score 0):

I'm baffled why this isn't something that exists already, and even more baffled why more developers aren't screaming their heads off demanding this. There is an undeniable need for dynamically created visual representations of sql queries. Trying to understand a single 300 line sql procudure is difficult enough without column names obfuscating their business representation using names like "AsecRemFortsKilnNumAttr".

When there are hundreds of columns in a procedure with names like this, but subtly different, like "AsecRemAgsKilnNumAttr" and "AsecRemFortsKilnNumV" as well then the task is impossible.

Anyway, here are a couple I've found: -

https://sqldep.com/sql-parser/

http://queryviz.com/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/revj/

The last one contains a Python utility that you can use to improve and extend if you know how.

Other than that the only other tool that may allow what you're looking for is Informatica Developer 10 which allows you to create a mapping from imported sql queries.

Comment: I use this: https://www.activedbsoft.com/download-querytool.html

Answer (score 0):

In essence there are 3 use cases for getting a visual representation of SQL code:

- Reverse engineering someone else's code. A graphical diagram can give
  you a helicopter view of the structure of SQL code. Clicking on the
  graphical element highlights the code that is representative of the
  component.
- You need to debug some complex SQL with multiple levels of nesting. A
  visual diagram can give you a tree view on how inline views or CTEs
  are nested and how the relate to each other.
- Documentation

We have created FlowHigh SQL Visualiser which is a [free online tool to visualise SQL](https://sonra.io/flowhigh/from-code-to-clarity-visualizing-sql-code-for-documentation-and-debugging/).

It has the following features:

- Detects and visualises physical tables, CTEs, inline views, pseudo tables, recursive CTEs, and function tables
- Expand and collapse nested components such as inline views and drill into the details of the SQL tree
- Navigate SQL code by clicking on elements on the diagram
- Browsing and searching SQL
- Export the diagram for documentation purposes
- Expand and collapse column names

Disclaimer: I work for the makers of FlowHigh

[image]

Answer (score -1):

SQL queries are usually represented in tree form, structured based on how the query is parsed (logical plan) or how the query engine will execute the query (physical plan)

See abstract syntax tree (AST) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree as an example
[image: Abstract Syntax Tree]